# SQL join showing duplicates in left table

Tags: php, sql, join, duplicates

I´m building a car rental system, I have 2 tables, one for the cars and one for the renting. I only want everything in the table 1 to be showed once, and everything that´s in the table 2 to be showed under table 1.

Let's say that my tables look like this:

### Table 1

- id
- car
- model

### Table 2

- id(same as table 1 id)
- rentstart
- rentstop
- renttimestart
- renttimestop`

**And I want it to be showed like this in a table:**

- Carid(t1) / car(t1) / model(t1)
- rentstart(t2)-rentstop(t2) / renttimestart(t2)-Renttimestop(t2)

**EXAMPLE:**

- 1 / BMW / 320
- 14.3.2013-14.3.2013 / 13:30-14:30
- 15.3.2013-15.3.2013 / 8:00-13:00
- 2 / Audi / A4
- 15.3.2013-15.3.2013 / 8:00-13:00

**This is what I have now:**

```
 $sqlquery = 
  "SELECT * FROM table1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
   GROUP BY table1.id";
```

(sorry for my formatting)

Comment: I suggest that you use sql to simply get the data and php to organize and display it in your application.  I don't use php but that's the approach I would take with ColdFusion.

Comment: Welcome, this appears to be your first ever question. Please remember to leave comment feedback if you need further help. If your question is answered, remember to tick the valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the query first as so:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id";
```

This will provide all the records you need per id (multiple rows). Then you need to filter your records in php using a statement (for,foreach,etc).

Flow would be as follows:

1. Perform query
2. Then foreach record check id, if id is different from previous id or 0 then echo `Carid(t1) / car(t1) / model(t1)`
3. Otherwise echo `rentstart(t2)-rentstop(t2) / renttimestart(t2)-Renttimestop(t2)`

Hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all cars to be listed only once and supply all corresponding rentals by car, you should use some kind of loop. Since you didn't supply the database you are using, I can only give you pseudo code:

```
 $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table1";
 *execute query*
 while ($car = *fetch*) {
     *print car data*
     $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM table2 where id = ?";
     *execute inner query with parameter binding: $car["id"]*
     while ($rent = *fetch*) {
         *print rent data*
     }
 }
```

General hint: Use a primary key on your second table and rename "id" to "carid". Avoids confusion.

Comment: Running queries inside loops is inefficient and in this case, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create store procedure if you want everything to be done in sql:

```
declare @Table1 table
(
  Id int, 
  Car  varchar(100), 
  Model  varchar(100)
)
Insert into @Table1 values
Select ID,Car,model From Table1

Declare @Temp Table
(
    FinalValue varchar(300)
)

Declare @id int

While ((Select Count(*) From @Table1)>0)
Begin
 Set @id =(Select Top 1 id From @Table1)
 Insert Into @Temp 
 Select cast(id as varchar(5))+'/'+car+'/'+model From @Table1 Where Id=@id

 Insert @Temp Select rentstart+'-'+rentstop +'/'+ renttimestart+'-'+Renttimestop From Table2 Where Id=@id

 Delete From @Table1 Where Id=@id
End

Select * From @Temp
```

Output:

```
1/BMW /320
14.3.2013-14.3.2013/13:30-14:30
15.3.2013-15.3.2013/8:00-13:30
2/Audi/A4
15.3.2013-15.3.2013/8:00-13:30
```